# PHP PDO CRUD display data based on select box value

Tags: php, pdo, drop-down-menu, crud

i was doing practice of PHP PDO CRUD example of codingcage ...link is http://www.codingcage.com/2015/04/php-pdo-crud-tutorial-using-oop-with.html
-- in index.php i have created a select box with dynamic value :

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'kk') or die ('Cannot connect to db');

$result = $conn->query("SELECT DISTINCT project FROM tbl_activitymaster where ProjectFlag='open' ");

echo "<html>";
echo "<body>";
echo "<select name='unqprj'>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

              unset($project, $project);
              $project = $row['project'];
              $name = $row['project']; 
              echo '<option value="'.$project.'">'.$project.'</option>';
              $value="<?php echo $project;?>";
             }

echo "</select>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
```

But the problem is that how to use this select box in the crud example to filter the records based on the value selected . I have done it in asp.net but in php how to do this. any help please or any link

---

```
// as mulder is suggesting but no idea how to implement with this eaample
<form action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>' method='post'  name='form2' >
<select name="value">
<option value="all">All</option>
<option value="Project1">Project1</option>
<option value="Project2">Project2</option>
</select>   
<input type='submit' value = 'Show'>
</form>
```

---

```
class.crud.php..............
//show
public function dataview($query)
{
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->rowCount()>0)
{
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
?>
<td><?php print($row['id']); ?></td>        
<td><?php print($row['Project']);?></td>
<td><?php print($row['ProjectUser']);?></td>                
<td><?php print($row['Month']);?></td>
<td><?php print($row['Status']);?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
}
else
{
?>
<tr>
<td>Nothing here...</td>
</tr>
<?php
}
}


//paging    
    public function paging($query,$records_per_page)
    {
    $starting_position=0;
    if(isset($_GET["page_no"]))
    {
    $starting_position=($_GET["page_no"]-1)*$records_per_page;
    }
    $query2=$query." limit $starting_position,$records_per_page";
    return $query2;
    }
```

---

```
index.php...............
<?php include_once '../header.php'; ?>
<?php include_once 'dbconfig.php'; ?>
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'kk') 
or die ('Cannot connect to db');
$result = $conn->query("SELECT DISTINCT project FROM tbl_activitymaster where ProjectFlag='open' ");
echo "<html>";
echo "<body>";
echo "<select name='unqprj'>";
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
unset($project, $project);
$project = $row['project'];
$name = $row['project']; 
echo '<option value="'.$project.'">'.$project.'</option>';
$value="<?php echo $project;?>";
echo "</select>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
?>
<div class="container">
<table class='table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive'>
<thead style="background-color:#FFFBF0">
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Project</th>
<th>ProjectUser</th>
<th>Month</th>
<th>Status</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_activitymaster where ProjectUser='" . ($_SESSION['sess_username']) . "' ";       
$records_per_page=10;
$newquery = $crud->paging($query,$records_per_page);
$crud->dataview($newquery);
?>
<tr>
<td colspan="7" align="center">
<div class="pagination-wrap">
<?php $crud->paginglink($query,$records_per_page); ?>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<?php include_once '../footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Create a form, use `$_POST` array.

Comment: thanks mulder for your quick response . i am not getting any idea how to implement it with this crud -pdo example. any help

Answer (score 0):

Here the code of codeingcage firstly and you need to just inject select box over there like:

**Index.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
?>
<?php include_once 'header.php'; ?>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="container">
<a href="add-data.php" class="btn btn-large btn-info"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> &nbsp; Add Records</a>
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div><br />

<div class="container">
     <table class='table table-bordered table-responsive'>
     <tr>
     <th>#</th>
     <th>First Name</th>
     <th>Last Name</th>
     <th>E - mail ID</th>
     <th>Contact No</th>
     <th colspan="2" align="center">Actions</th>
     </tr>
     <?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users";       
        $records_per_page=3;
        $newquery = $crud->paging($query,$records_per_page);
        $crud->dataview($newquery);
     ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="7" align="center">
            <div class="pagination-wrap">
            <?php $crud->paginglink($query,$records_per_page); ?>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>


</div>

<?php include_once 'footer.php'; ?>
```

**dbconfig.php**

```
<?php

$DB_host = "localhost";
$DB_user = "root";
$DB_pass = "";
$DB_name = "dbpdo";


try
{
    $DB_con = new PDO("mysql:host={$DB_host};dbname={$DB_name}",$DB_user,$DB_pass);
    $DB_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

include_once 'class.crud.php';

$crud = new crud($DB_con);

?>
```

**class.crud.php**

```
<?php

class crud
{
    private $db;

    function __construct($DB_con)
    {
        $this->db = $DB_con;
    }

    public function create($fname,$lname,$email,$contact)
    {
        try
        {
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_users(first_name,last_name,email_id,contact_no) VALUES(:fname, :lname, :email, :contact)");
            $stmt->bindparam(":fname",$fname);
            $stmt->bindparam(":lname",$lname);
            $stmt->bindparam(":email",$email);
            $stmt->bindparam(":contact",$contact);
            $stmt->execute();
            return true;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();  
            return false;
        }

    }

    public function getID($id)
    {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE id=:id");
        $stmt->execute(array(":id"=>$id));
        $editRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $editRow;
    }

    public function update($id,$fname,$lname,$email,$contact)
    {
        try
        {
            $stmt=$this->db->prepare("UPDATE tbl_users SET first_name=:fname, 
                                                       last_name=:lname, 
                                                       email_id=:email, 
                                                       contact_no=:contact
                                                    WHERE id=:id ");
            $stmt->bindparam(":fname",$fname);
            $stmt->bindparam(":lname",$lname);
            $stmt->bindparam(":email",$email);
            $stmt->bindparam(":contact",$contact);
            $stmt->bindparam(":id",$id);
            $stmt->execute();

            return true;    
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();  
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM tbl_users WHERE id=:id");
        $stmt->bindparam(":id",$id);
        $stmt->execute();
        return true;
    }

    /* paging */

    public function dataview($query)
    {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();

        if($stmt->rowCount()>0)
        {
            while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                ?>
                <tr>
                <td><?php print($row['id']); ?></td>
                <td><?php print($row['first_name']); ?></td>
                <td><?php print($row['last_name']); ?></td>
                <td><?php print($row['email_id']); ?></td>
                <td><?php print($row['contact_no']); ?></td>
                <td align="center">
                <a href="edit-data.php?edit_id=<?php print($row['id']); ?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                <a href="delete.php?delete_id=<?php print($row['id']); ?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i></a>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ?>
            <tr>
            <td>Nothing here...</td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }

    }

    public function paging($query,$records_per_page)
    {
        $starting_position=0;
        if(isset($_GET["page_no"]))
        {
            $starting_position=($_GET["page_no"]-1)*$records_per_page;
        }
        $query2=$query." limit $starting_position,$records_per_page";
        return $query2;
    }

    public function paginglink($query,$records_per_page)
    {

        $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();

        $total_no_of_records = $stmt->rowCount();

        if($total_no_of_records > 0)
        {
            ?><ul class="pagination"><?php
            $total_no_of_pages=ceil($total_no_of_records/$records_per_page);
            $current_page=1;
            if(isset($_GET["page_no"]))
            {
                $current_page=$_GET["page_no"];
            }
            if($current_page!=1)
            {
                $previous =$current_page-1;
                echo "<li><a href='".$self."?page_no=1'>First</a></li>";
                echo "<li><a href='".$self."?page_no=".$previous."'>Previous</a></li>";
            }
            for($i=1;$i<=$total_no_of_pages;$i++)
            {
                if($i==$current_page)
                {
                    echo "<li><a href='".$self."?page_no=".$i."' style='color:red;'>".$i."</a></li>";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<li><a href='".$self."?page_no=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>";
                }
            }
            if($current_page!=$total_no_of_pages)
            {
                $next=$current_page+1;
                echo "<li><a href='".$self."?page_no=".$next."'>Next</a></li>";
                echo "<li><a href='".$self."?page_no=".$total_no_of_pages."'>Last</a></li>";
            }
            ?></ul><?php
        }
    }

    /* paging */

}
```

**add-data.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
if(isset($_POST['btn-save']))
{
    $fname = $_POST['first_name'];
    $lname = $_POST['last_name'];
    $email = $_POST['email_id'];
    $contact = $_POST['contact_no'];

    if($crud->create($fname,$lname,$email,$contact))
    {
        header("Location: add-data.php?inserted");
    }
    else
    {
        header("Location: add-data.php?failure");
    }
}
?>
<?php include_once 'header.php'; ?>
<div class="clearfix"></div>

<?php
if(isset($_GET['inserted']))
{
    ?>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="alert alert-info">
    <strong>WOW!</strong> Record was inserted successfully <a href="index.php">HOME</a>!
    </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
else if(isset($_GET['failure']))
{
    ?>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
    <strong>SORRY!</strong> ERROR while inserting record !
    </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>

<div class="clearfix"></div><br />

<div class="container">


     <form method='post'>

    <table class='table table-bordered'>

        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='first_name' class='form-control' required></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='last_name' class='form-control' required></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Your E-mail ID</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='email_id' class='form-control' required></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Contact No</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='contact_no' class='form-control' required></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn-save">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Create New Record
            </button>  
            <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-large btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></i> &nbsp; Back to index</a>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>


</div>

<?php include_once 'footer.php'; ?>
```

**edit-data.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
if(isset($_POST['btn-update']))
{
    $id = $_GET['edit_id'];
    $fname = $_POST['first_name'];
    $lname = $_POST['last_name'];
    $email = $_POST['email_id'];
    $contact = $_POST['contact_no'];

    if($crud->update($id,$fname,$lname,$email,$contact))
    {
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-info'>
                <strong>WOW!</strong> Record was updated successfully <a href='index.php'>HOME</a>!
                </div>";
    }
    else
    {
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-warning'>
                <strong>SORRY!</strong> ERROR while updating record !
                </div>";
    }
}

if(isset($_GET['edit_id']))
{
    $id = $_GET['edit_id'];
    extract($crud->getID($id)); 
}

?>
<?php include_once 'header.php'; ?>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="container">
<?php
if(isset($msg))
{
    echo $msg;
}
?>
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div><br />

<div class="container">

     <form method='post'>

    <table class='table table-bordered'>

        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='first_name' class='form-control' value="<?php echo $first_name; ?>" required></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='last_name' class='form-control' value="<?php echo $last_name; ?>" required></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Your E-mail ID</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='email_id' class='form-control' value="<?php echo $email_id; ?>" required></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Contact No</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='contact_no' class='form-control' value="<?php echo $contact_no; ?>" required></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn-update">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>  Update this Record
                </button>
                <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-large btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></i> &nbsp; CANCEL</a>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>


</div>

<?php include_once 'footer.php'; ?>
```

**delete.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';

if(isset($_POST['btn-del']))
{
    $id = $_GET['delete_id'];
    $crud->delete($id);
    header("Location: delete.php?deleted"); 
}

?>

<?php include_once 'header.php'; ?>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="container">

    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['deleted']))
    {
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-success">
        <strong>Success!</strong> record was deleted... 
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <strong>Sure !</strong> to remove the following record ? 
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    ?>  
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="container">

     <?php
     if(isset($_GET['delete_id']))
     {
         ?>
         <table class='table table-bordered'>
         <tr>
         <th>#</th>
         <th>First Name</th>
         <th>Last Name</th>
         <th>E - mail ID</th>
         <th>Gender</th>
         </tr>
         <?php
         $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE id=:id");
         $stmt->execute(array(":id"=>$_GET['delete_id']));
         while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH))
         {
             ?>
             <tr>
             <td><?php print($row['id']); ?></td>
             <td><?php print($row['first_name']); ?></td>
             <td><?php print($row['last_name']); ?></td>
             <td><?php print($row['email_id']); ?></td>
             <td><?php print($row['contact_no']); ?></td>
             </tr>
             <?php
         }
         ?>
         </table>
         <?php
     }
     ?>
</div>

<div class="container">
<p>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['delete_id']))
{
    ?>
    <form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit" name="btn-del"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> &nbsp; YES</button>
    <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-large btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></i> &nbsp; NO</a>
    </form>  
    <?php
}
else
{
    ?>
    <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-large btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></i> &nbsp; Back to index</a>
    <?php
}
?>
</p>
</div>  
<?php include_once 'footer.php'; ?>
```

**MY SQL :**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_users` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `first_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL, `last_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL, `email_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL, `contact_no` bigint(10) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=21
```

> Still adding your selectbox and will update this answer soon.